# Long delay in JBoss start time

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x

I'm running JBoss 7.1.1.Final and a fresh install of Eclipse (Juno). The JBoss server runs fine once it's started but I've noticed there is a long delay every time I try to start it. Take a look below, the first three lines pop into the console instantly, then it seems like nothing happens for two minutes. When it starts up again the rest of the server start takes about 30 seconds.

```
13:07:39,406 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:07:43,357 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:07:43,498 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
13:10:12,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
...
13:10:45,380 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "test-ear.ear"
```

Does anyone know what is going on in the time between lines 3 and 4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that it is performing a scan of your deployment. Turn on debug level logging for the category "org.jboss.modules" to see if the scanning is taking up this time.

Also check if you have anti-virus scanning turned on for the deployment directory (exclude this directory) since that can slow down startup as well.

Comment: I turned on logging and did see a deployment scan in there just as the two minute gap in startup ended. Is that normal (a two minute scan every time you start the server)? And if not, what could be done about it?

Comment: @MikeC did you get the answer on how to bypass deployment scan?